# Find lines between a pattern, and append 1st line to lines

Tags: powershell, text-parsing

I have the following case I'm trying to script in Powershell. I have done this exercise using Sed on a bash terminal, but having trouble writing in Powershell.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.
    (`sed -r -e '/^N/h;/^[N-]/d;G;s/(.*)\n(.*)/\2 \1/' <file>`, with a file format without `<` and `>` chars. surrounding the first letter on each line)

The start pattern always start with a `<N>` (only 1 instance per block), lines between start with a `<J>`, and the end pattern is always `--`

```
--------------
<N>ABC123
<J>SomethingHere1
<J>SomethingHere2
<J>SomethingHere3
--------------    <-- end of section
```

I'm trying to take the first line in each section `<N>` and copy it AFTER each `<J>` in the same section.  For example:

```
<J>SomethingHere1    <N>ABC123
<J>SomethingHere2    <N>ABC123
<J>SomethingHere3    <N>ABC123
```

The number of `<J>` lines per section can vary (0-N).  In a case with no `<J>`, nothing needs to be done.

Powershell version:5.1.16299.611

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following, **pipeline-based** solution **isn't fast**, but **conceptually straightforward**:

```
Get-Content file.txt | ForEach-Object {
  if ($_ -match '^-+$') { $newSect = $true }
  elseif ($newSect) { $firstSectionLine = $_; $newSect = $False }
  else { "{0}`t{1}" -f $_, $firstSectionLine }
}
```

- It reads and processes lines one by one (with the line at hand reflected in automatic variable `$_`.
- It uses a regex (`^-+`) with the `-match` operator to identify section dividers; if found, flag `$newSect` is set to signal that the *next* line is the section's first data line.
- If the first data line is hit, it is cached in variable `$firstSectionLine`, and the `$newSect` flag is reset.
- All other lines are by definition the lines to which the first data line is to be appended, which is done via the `-f` string-formatting operator, using a tab char. (`` `t ``) as the separator.

---

Here's a **faster PSv4+ solution** that is **more complex**, however, and it **reads the entire input file into memory up front**:

```
((Get-Content -Raw file.txt) -split '(?m)^-+(?:\r?\n)?' -ne '').ForEach({
  $firstLine, $otherLines = $_ -split '\r?\n' -ne ''
  foreach ($otherLine in $otherLines) { "{0}`t{1}" -f $otherLine, $firstLine }
})
```

- `Get-Content -Raw` reads in the input file in full, as a single string.
- It uses the `-split` operator to split the input file into sections, and then processes each section.
- Regex `'(?m)^-+(?:\r?\n)?'` matches a section divider line, optionally followed by a newline.

  - `(?m)` is the multiline option, which makes `^` and `$` match the start and end of each *line*, respectively:
  - `\r?\n` matches a newline, either in CRLF (`\r\n`) or LF-only (`\n`) form.
  - `(?:...)` is a non-capturing group; making it non-capturing prevents what it matches from being included in the elements returned by `-split`.
  - `-ne ''` filters out resulting empty elements.
- `-split '\r?\n'` splits each section into individual lines.

If performance is still a concern, you could speed up reading the file with `[IO.File]::ReadAllText("$PWD/file.txt")`.